# Lock pick on shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

Is it permissible to use a lock pick on shabbos?
 Obviously an electronic one would be prohibited.

what are the possible prohibitions?

Comment: Why wouold you want to? Note that it would be asur outside of an eruv just as a key would be asur. Also it may be muktzah as a *kli shemelachto asur*, an object whose use is forbidden.

Comment: @Sabba what is the issur being done that would make this into a kli shemilachto li'issur?

Comment: https://library.yctorah.org/lindenbaum/uvda-dchol-on-shabbat/

Comment: If it is being used for committing a crime

Comment: Why would you think it’s okay/not okay?

Comment: @sabba I'm assuming that response was meant for me? That is not what kli shemilachto li'isur means. It means a kli used for an act which is assur as a melacha on shabbos. Not a global issur.

Answer (score 5):

The mishnah ([Shabbos 17:2/122b](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=122b&format=pdf)) mentions "a sackmaker's needle" as an example of a muktzah utensil with a permissible use, "to open a door with it" (Rashi: "if he lost his key") - i.e., to pick the lock.

[Rambam, Shabbos 25:7](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=1691&rtype=%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%98), quotes this as halachah, although oddly Tur and Shulchan Aruch don't. (I wonder if that's just because of changes in technology, that by their times locks were made differently, and needles wouldn't work for the purpose?) Radvaz ([teshuvah 1503](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_5.1503?vhe=Teshuvot_HaRadbaz,_Warsaw_1882&lang=he), end), though, mentions such use as being permissible on Shabbos in order to get food out of a locked cabinet (and preferable to breaking the door, though he allows that too if there's no other way).